# При клике на другой элемент данные старого удаляются и записываются новые

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ситуация следующая: выгружаю список с сервера. у этого списка есть еще связи, которые мне при клике на элемент необходимо показать. То есть, при клике на элемент создается `<p>` и там записывается информация. 
Как при клике на другой элемент удалить информацию, которая писалась предыдущим и написать свою?

Хожу вокруг да около ответа, но все никак не могу додуматься.

```js
function showCompanies(companies) {
  for (var i = 0; i < companies.list.length; i++) {
    var li = companiesList.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    li.innerHTML = companies.list[i].name;

    //show partners
    //track 'li' number which has been clicked and show it partners
    li.onclick = function(a) {
      var a = a || window.event,
        a = a.target || a.srcElement,
        b = a.parentNode;
      if (a.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li" && b.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "ul") {
        for (var current = 0, a = a.previousSibling; a && a != b;) {
          a.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "li" && current++, a = a.previousSibling;
        }
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < companies.list[current].partners.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById('companyPartners').style.display = 'block';
        var partnersBlock = document.getElementById('partners');
        var p = partnersBlock.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        p.innerHTML = companies.list[current].partners[j].name;
      }
    }

  };
}
```

Итак, что тут происходит...я перетягиваю из файла компании в список, далее при клике отслеживаю порядковый номер в массиве, чтоб по нему узнать данные о партнерах этой компании, я их узнаю и вывожу на экран. Осталось теперь при клике на другой элемент удалить предыдущих партнеров и показать новых.

Comment: покажите код...

Comment: вы испугаетесь)) там вряд ли что-то будет понятно, так как функция с этими действиями одна, а данные берет по всей программе.. через 3 минуты обновлю вопрос

Comment: @L.Vadim отредактировал